Remove X-Forwarded-Prefix header from Spring Cloud Gateway Route
Trying to remove x-Forwarded-Prefix header from one of route in spring cloud gateway but it is not working.
Tried below.
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=X-Forwarded-Prefix
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RequestHeader=X-Forwarded-Prefix,
spring.cloud.gateway.x-forwarded-prefix.enabled=false
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[19].filters[0]=AddRequestHeader=X-Forwarded-Prefix,

None of them worked. After debugging I found the header is still exist in org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.headers.observation.ObservedRequestHttpHeadersFilter#filter method

server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
is causing the issue. If you set the value to framework it is appending the X-Forwarded-Prefix path to your actual URL.
Removed it and the issue is resolved.
